# align also ylabels in a TikZ matrix

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

I am aligning many `pgfplots` with the TikZ `\matrix`. The axes are automatically aligned correctly. How can I also align the `ylabels` automatically (because I am changing plotted data very often)?

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix{
       \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth,ylabel={ylabel 1}]
           \addplot {x^2};
        \end{axis}
        \\
        \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth,ylabel={ylabel 2}]
            \addplot {-(x^2)};
        \end{axis}
        \\  
     };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Not desired output:

[image: not desired]

Desired output:

[image: desired]

Again I had a close look at:

- Manual for `pgfplots` by Christian Feuersaenger
- Manual for `TikZ` & `PGF` by Till Tantau

---

### edit

thanks! Especially the the finer control is really good.

Unfortunately now -- with this `ylabel absolute` -- linebreaks with `\\` or `\newline` aren't possible anymore :-(

Is there a trick?

not working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=newest,
 /pgfplots/myylabel absolute/.style={%
  /pgfplots/every axis y label/.style={at={(0,0.5)},xshift=#1,rotate=90},
  /pgfplots/every y tick scale label/.style={
   at={(0,1)},above right,inner sep=0pt,yshift=0.3em
   }
   }
 }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix{
   \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth,ylabel={ylabel  1 first line\\second line},myylabel absolute=-60]
       \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}
    \\
    \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth,ylabel={ylabel 2 first line\\second line},,myylabel absolute=-60]
        \addplot {-(x^2)};
    \end{axis}
    \\  
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I added a new option to my updated answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution for the new requirement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `ylabel absolute` option (pages 173 and 174 of the `pgfplots` manual) produces the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix{
       \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth,ylabel={ylabel 1},ylabel absolute]
           \addplot {x^2};
        \end{axis}
        \\
        \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth,ylabel={ylabel 2},ylabel absolute]
            \addplot {-(x^2)};
        \end{axis}
        \\  
     };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want even finer control, you can define a style in a similar fashion to `ylabel absolute`, but allowing you to specify, through an argument, the desired shifting (`ylabel absolute` uses `-35pt`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=newest,
/pgfplots/myylabel absolute/.style={%
  /pgfplots/every axis y label/.style={at={(0,0.5)},xshift=#1,rotate=90},
  /pgfplots/every y tick scale label/.style={
    at={(0,1)},above right,inner sep=0pt,yshift=0.3em
   }
  }
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix{
       \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth,ylabel={ylabel 1},myylabel absolute=-30pt]
           \addplot {x^2};
        \end{axis}
        \\
        \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth,ylabel={ylabel 2},,myylabel absolute=-30pt]
            \addplot {-(x^2)};
        \end{axis}
        \\  
     };
\end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix{
       \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth,ylabel={ylabel 1},myylabel absolute=-40pt]
           \addplot {x^2};
        \end{axis}
        \\
        \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth,ylabel={ylabel 2},,myylabel absolute=-40pt]
            \addplot {-(x^2)};
        \end{axis}
        \\  
     };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After the edit to the original question: the problem is that you are trying to use labels with more than one line of text; in order to do so, you can, for example, use the `align=<value>` option for the label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=newest,
 /pgfplots/myylabel absolute/.style={%
  /pgfplots/every axis y label/.style={at={(0,0.5)},xshift=#1,rotate=90,align=center},
  /pgfplots/every y tick scale label/.style={
   at={(0,1)},above right,inner sep=0pt,yshift=0.3em
   }
 }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix{
   \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth,ylabel={ylabel  1 first line\\second line},myylabel absolute=-50]
       \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}
    \\
    \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.45\textwidth,ylabel={ylabel 2 first line\\second line},myylabel absolute=-50]
        \addplot {-(x^2)};
    \end{axis}
    \\  
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! works great and I am 99 % satisfied :-) The last 1 % would be to get the modified picture really centered over the caption :-)

Comment: @BenjaminMassow by default, the whole picture (including the labels) is centered with respect to the caption; if you want to exclude the labels, you can use `trim axis left` for `tikzpicture`, as in `\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]...`\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: :-) that's it, thx!